# Cannot Fire Backbone JS Events using MVC3 Web Site ( Complete Beginner ) Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, events, razor, backbone.js

As part of preparation for an Interview I have been asked to read up on my MVC skills along with JavaScript which I believe will include Backbone and Spine Frame Works.

I have read a lot of websites but all sorts of different ways have been done and yet I cant fathom a simple example. So far I have the following...

A simple 'cshtml' file with a div and a button...

```
<div id="AuthorSection">
    <button id="sayhello">Add Author</button>
</div>
```

and an Author JS file which alerts me when it has rendered, but not when the event has been fired...

```
(function ($) {
Authors = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#AuthorSection'),
    events: { 'click #AddAuthor': 'AddNewAuthor'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'AddNewAuthor');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
    },

    AddNewAuthor: function (e) {
        alert('Adding Author');
    }
});

var Authors = new Authors;

})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be appreciated for someone very new to this type of work....

Thanks

Comment: <div id="AuthorSection">
        <button id="AddAuthor">Add Author</button>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is executed after the DOM is loaded, it should work as this Fiddle demonstrates http://jsfiddle.net/VcHn8/

On the other hand, if you execute your code before the DOM is loaded, $('#AuthorSection') is unknown at the time. Remove the el declaration in your view and replace

```
var Authors = new Authors;
```

by

```
$(function(){
    new Authors( {el: $('#AuthorSection')} );
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/C5HXH/1/

And you should name your variables something different than the name of your constructor

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an incorrect selector in your events hash.

The `id` of the button is `sayhello`, so you will need to update your events hash like this:

```
events: { 'click #sayhello': 'AddNewAuthor'
```

Comment: Apologies I noticed that error and tried to comments before anyone noticed, I have updated the button to "<button id="AddAuthor">Add Author</button>" but still have the same problem.Thanks.